# Codeigniter 4 Search Pagination not counting and returning page

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, codeigniter-4

I'm working on a simple search project where I'm returning the results. The search function appears to work however, the total and page return the wrong values. The total field returns the total number of rows inside the data, not the total number of results from the search and the page is always {}.

Here's the model->function I've created:

```
 public function search($string)
{

    $results = $this->select('*')->orLike('title', $string)->orLike('excerpt', $string);

    if ( empty( $results ) )
    {
        return [];
    
    } else 
    {
        $data = [
            'results' => $results->paginate(2),
            'total'   => $results->countAllResults(),
            'page'    => $this->pager,
            
        ];

        return $data;

    }
}
```

What's puzzling is if I place the total field above the results value the count works, but then the result fields returns everything in the database at paginate(2).

Comment: *paginate* appears to be a custom function.  Did you make it?

Comment: No paginate is delivered via the query API in CI 4

Comment: You might want to check that as I am aware of the Pagination Class, but not a function called `paginate()`.  The `countAllResults` also looks like a custom function as well (as a simple `count($results)` solves this).  I am curious how you call the DB with a single `$this`.  Usually the db class is a separate item, so `$this->db` or `$db`...but i've never called it as `$this`

Comment: When using Models via `use CodeIgniter\Model;` you have direct access to the db along with some other goodies without needing extra fluff.  See https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html. I managed to solve this earlier so I'll update this question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve this query by adding two separate queries to the database. The processing cost appears to be minimal and it should be alright when caching the responses. As it turns out you can chain queries but only in a particular order and if you use grouping (see ->groupStart() )

```
  $results = $this->select('title, image, categories, id, excerpt')->groupStart()->like('title', $search)->orLike('excerpt', $search)->groupEnd()->where('status','live')->paginate(2);
  $total   = $this->select('title, image, categories, id, excerpt')->groupStart()->like('title', $search)->orLike('excerpt', $search)->groupEnd()->where('status','live')->countAllResults();
```

Some may argue the inefficiency of the two queries, but this works for my use case :) Hope this helps anyone else stuck on a similar problem.